# How to hide/show the fields based on Picklist value

Tags: apex

How to Hide/Show the fields based on Picklist value

Having Picklist (Device) and Value (A, B, C, D)
having fields AA1, AA2, BB1, BB2, CC1, CC2 & DD1, DD2

If i will select value A from the picklist the AA2 will display and AA1 will hide.

If i will select value B from the picklist the BB2 will display and BB1 will hide.

If i will select value C from the picklist the CC2 will display and CC1 will hide.

If i will select value D from the picklist the DD2 will display and DD1 will hide.

I am using process builder on this for some other purpose.
If it is possible to solve this issue without any code, please share the solution.

Comment: Do you want in vf page? looks like you have added apex tag in question

Comment: @Ratan - i am using all the above stuff in my standard object, without use of any code.

Comment: So, basically, a Dependant Picklist via Process Builder?

Comment: Sachin, if you are using the standard view and AA1, BB1, et al are fields then you cannot do what you need. Fields can't be shown/hidden dynamically from a standard page layout. If you want VF then you can.

Comment: @SebastianKessel any live example (code) can you share with me?

Comment: To do this in Visualforce? Sure! I'll add it as an answer

Comment: vote for this IDEA: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BroxAAC

Answer (score 2):

Sachin, per your comment in the OP, here is a sample on how to achieve this in Visualforce. I picked the account object, just pick a new object if you prefer. You also may want to make the screen "pretty". (By using pageBlockSections and the like)

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">

<apex:form id="theForm">

  <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Device__c}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="theForm" />
</apex:inputField>

  <apex:inputField value="{!Account.AA2__c}" rendered="{!Account.Device__c == 'A'}" />
  <apex:inputField value="{!Account.AA1__c}" rendered="{! Account.Device__c != 'A'}" />

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Let me know if you want me to make this example more complex, but it will give you an idea on how to approach the problem.